# I want to create a chatapp in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have created a chatapp just like Angela Yu did in her course of flutter, but I want to create a chatapp e.g 5 users got registered into my app and then they would be able to text privately the desired person (using the email with which this desired person is registered in app) and the texts will be visible to these two persons, not to all the registered people.  Need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this article.

[Build a chat app with flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-a-chat-app-with-flutter-and-firebase-from-scratch-9eaa7f41782e)

It leads you through the process of creating a chat app in flutter using `Firebase`

I hope this answered your question.

**UPDATED** check the article below:
[Chat app with flutter firebase](https://itnext.io/flutter-firebase-auth-starter-project-b0f91a6503b7)

Comment: He is using google sign in method. This is nice.  I need email and password method. I will be happy if you could suggest me that Sir.

Comment: Check my answer I updated it already. The other article uses email and password sign in.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want firebase as your app backend, I started a flutter project to use MQTT protocol as chat backend. You can check it here:
https://github.com/WahidNasri/flutter-mqtt-chat-client